# replace older resources file with newest at flavours

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In my project I have 2 flavour. in main module I have a raw folder contain a json file.In my flavour I need to change this json file.I have created this file into raw folder at res folder in my flavour and according this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html#change_your_resource_directory)

I added this line to my build.gradle:

```
    productFlavors {
    main {

    }
    abfa {
        applicationIdSuffix ".abfa"
        versionName '1.1.61-Abfa'
        sourceSets {
            res.raw = ['resources/abfa']
        }
    }
```

but I got this error:

```
Error:(98, 0) Could not set unknown property 'raw' for source set res of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet.
```

how could I replace older resources file with newest at every flavour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create in the folder of your flavor same file structure tree as in main flavor folder.

See as in example

[image]

Here I've got flavor *global_dev* additionally and if it is chosen one, then its resources are overriding the main flavor resources. Then this line

```
sourceSets {
        res.raw = ['resources/abfa']
    }
```

is not needed.